# Bonjour bookmarks not supported?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, bonjour

I was trying to get Bonjour bookmarks to show up in Safari on iPad and I came across this post from 2008 - "Safari for iPhone currently doesn't support Bonjour bookmark browsing":
http://lists.apple.com/archives/safari-iphone-web-dev/2008/Aug/msg00008.html

Is this still not implemented 4 years later?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an answer from Apple:

> > Is this still not implemented 4 years later?
>
> Yes )-: Please file a bug about this, describing the specific use case you have in mind.
> http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/
>
> Quinn "The Eskimo!" eskimo1@apple.com
>
> Apple Developer Relations, Developer Technical Support, Core OS/Hardware

Update: I raised the issue and got a reply saying it was a duplicate of Bug ID# 5553678, but I can't view this.